# Hilbert polynomial for any invertible sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over algebraically closed field $k$, $L$ is invertible sheaf on $X$ and $\mathcal F \in \operatorname{Coh}(X)$ , we define Hilbert polynomial $P_{\mathcal F}(n)=\chi(\mathcal F \otimes L^n).$ Is there any way to prove that $P$ is polynomial not using Riemann-Roch and Chern classes. I think that there should be some argument similar to mdeland's argument([Why is the Euler characteristic of powers of a line bundle a polynomial in the power?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/889/why-is-the-euler-characteristic-of-powers-of-a-line-bundle-a-polynomial-in-the-p)), which works for locally free $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Why should something be proved without using very simple and standard techniques?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Hilbert polynomial of a projective variety, say as outlined in Hartshorne I.7?

Comment: @BenLim Yes, I'm able to prove it in the case of very ample $L$.

Answer (score 7):

Prove that $\chi (\mathcal F \otimes L_1^{n} \otimes L_2^m)$ is a polynomial function of $n$ and $m$ of degree $d$ when $L_1$ and $L_2$ are very ample. You can do this by exactly the same induction argument. (If you have a function of two variables whose successive differences in both variables are degree $d-1$ polynomials, then it is a degree $d$ polynomial.)

Then write your divisor as a difference of two ample divisors and set $m=-n$.